# React Native Detox - Local and CI have different outcomes

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

I am having strange issue with React Native Detox testing when being ran on local and CI environments.

Following is the piece of code being ran on both of the environments:

```
import { E2E_IDS } from './constants';
import {
    executeBeforeEachTest,
    tapById,
    testAccount,
    typeTextById,
    waitForId,
    waitForText,
} from './utils';

describe('User email sign in flow test', () => {
    beforeEach(executeBeforeEachTest);

    it('should login with provided user credentials successfully', async () => {
        await tapById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN);
        await waitForText('Welcome back');
        await tapById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN_VIA_EMAIL);
        await typeTextById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN_EMAIL, testAccount.USER);
        await typeTextById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN_PASSWORD, testAccount.PASS);
        await tapById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN_LOGIN_BUTTON);
        await waitForText('You have no classes yet.');
    });
});
```

On my local mac machine, e2e tests runs fine as expected.

On Github CI mac machine, e2e fails because single tap on SIGN_IN_LOGIN_BUTTON is not enough, if I do the following:

```
        await tapById(E2E_IDS.SIGN_IN_LOGIN_BUTTON, 2);
```

If we tap the button twice, then it passes the test. I wonder why the first tap is not being acknowledged by the CI machine, that we had to do twice.

If anyone could help narrow down the root cause of this behaviour that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last issue was quite tricky, it was actually a UX bug. So, when user types their email and password in the login form, the keyboard doesn't drop when we tap on the login button, because we had a keyboard overlay which is blocking the login button being tapped. To circumvent this issue, we need to add keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' to the top level scrollView which will trigger down the tap events to it's child which will result in closing the keyboard plus the tap to right element, all in one go.
It was strange why this didn't happen on my local simulator, perhaps, we can toggle the keyboard on/off which didn't help me to narrow down the issue at hand.

Why 2 taps?
Because, first one was to drop the keyboard (inactive state) then the next one was to tap on the login button.